# Stack part of dataframe and then merge it into original dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble with using the `stack()` function on a section of a dataframe in pandas and then merging that stacked data back into the original dataframe.

To explain more understandably through an example, suppose I have the following df:

```
>>>df
        date  name favorite_color  day_1  day_2  day_3  day_4  count
0   1/9/2018   Tom           Blue     27     28     45     30     14
1  1/10/2018  Stan            Red     29     13     16      5     13
2  1/11/2018   Rob          Green     18      7      3      4     21
```

I want to "stack" the columns that start with 'day' and to do so I created a separate temporary dataframe with just those columns, and then stacked them via `stack()`

```
temp_df = df.loc[:,['day_1','day_2','day_3','day_4', 'count']]
temp_df = temp_df.stack()  # this is now a Series, NOT a DataFrame
print(temp_df)
0  day_1    27
   day_2    28
   day_3    45
   day_4    30
   count    14
1  day_1    29
   day_2    13
   day_3    16
   day_4     5
   count    13
2  day_1    18
   day_2     7
   day_3     3
   day_4     4
   count    21
```

Now what I would like to do, which I can't seem to figure out and would really appreciate some help on, is to now merge this Series of stacked data back into the original dataframe so that I get the following:

```
>>>final_df
         date  name favorite_color time_frame  value
0    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue      day_1     27
1    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue      day_2     28
2    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue      day_3     45
3    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue      day_4     30
4    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue      count     14
5   1/10/2018  Stan            Red      day_1     29
6   1/10/2018  Stan            Red      day_2     13
7   1/10/2018  Stan            Red      day_3     16
8   1/10/2018  Stan            Red      day_4      5
9   1/10/2018  Stan            Red      count     13
10  1/11/2018   Rob          Green      day_1     18
11  1/11/2018   Rob          Green      day_2      7
12  1/11/2018   Rob          Green      day_3      3
13  1/11/2018   Rob          Green      day_4      4
14  1/11/2018   Rob          Green      count     21
```

Any pointers on this or suggestions for a better approach entirely would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC [wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,'day',i=['date','name','favorite_color'],j='days',sep='_').\
      rename(columns={'day':'value'}).\
        reset_index()
Out[1002]: 
         date  name favorite_color days  value
0    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue    1     27
1    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue    2     28
2    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue    3     45
3    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue    4     30
4   1/10/2018  Stan            Red    1     29
5   1/10/2018  Stan            Red    2     13
6   1/10/2018  Stan            Red    3     16
7   1/10/2018  Stan            Red    4      5
8   1/11/2018   Rob          Green    1     18
9   1/11/2018   Rob          Green    2      7
10  1/11/2018   Rob          Green    3      3
11  1/11/2018   Rob          Green    4      4
```

Update

```
tempdf= df.drop('count',1)
df1=pd.wide_to_long(tempdf,'day',i=['date','name','favorite_color'],j='days',sep='_').\
      rename(columns={'day':'value'}).\
        reset_index()
df2=df.set_index(['date','name','favorite_color'])[['count']].stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_3':'days',0:'value'})
pd.concat([df1,df2])
Out[24]: 
         date  name favorite_color   days  value
0    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue      1     27
1    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue      2     28
2    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue      3     45
3    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue      4     30
4   1/10/2018  Stan            Red      1     29
5   1/10/2018  Stan            Red      2     13
6   1/10/2018  Stan            Red      3     16
7   1/10/2018  Stan            Red      4      5
8   1/11/2018   Rob          Green      1     18
9   1/11/2018   Rob          Green      2      7
10  1/11/2018   Rob          Green      3      3
11  1/11/2018   Rob          Green      4      4
0    1/9/2018   Tom           Blue  count     14
1   1/10/2018  Stan            Red  count     13
2   1/11/2018   Rob          Green  count     21
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see that using `wide_to_long()` requires that the columns need to have a common stub name. I know I didn't include it in the example dataframe, but what if I also wanted to have a column be a part of the stack that does not start with 'day' (e.g. it's column name is 'count')? I've edited my question to reflect the new dataframe that I'm talking about

Comment: @DGav Check the update , also , would you like upvote and accept this , if its help

Comment: Awesome, yep absolutely gave upvote. Only issue is I would still like to preserve the order of the stack as shown in answer, rather than having counts at the bottom. Would that be as simple as a `sort_values(by="date")` ?

Comment: @DGav sort_values(by='name')